# Why can't VM-based Ubuntu access an SD card?

Tags: sd-card

I installed Ubuntu on a VMWare Virtual Machine (x86) on PC-Windows. I inserted an SD card on my PC, which shows drives inside it. I accessed the drives on PC File Manager successfully.

But in Linux side, I found "**/dev/sdb: Can't open blockdev**" at output of '**dmesg**'. I used command 'ls /dev/' and can't find 'sdb'.

What's wrong with it?

Comment: Does this help? https://communities.vmware.com/t5/VMware-Workstation-Player/Trouble-opening-SD-card-using-Ubuntu-VM-on-Workstation-Player-16/td-p/2882672

Comment: Unfortunately, no. I got "insufficient permission to access file" in the step "Specify disk file" and failed. So, what's wrong with it?